# Why I cannot just change the a href to a hardcoded url link?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the page http://zanifesto.com/product/boise-infographic/ go back to http://zanifesto.com/gallery, not the Infographics category page at the "Back to" link at the top.

When I replace the .home_url etc etc you see below with the gallery url mentioned above, it errors out.

I am looking to understand why the php code doesn't act like I am replacing one url for another.

```
<div class="product_navigation desktops">

            <?php
                $term_list = '';
                $j=0;
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    if($term->parent==0){
                        $j++;
                        if( $j <= 1 ){
                            $term_list .= '<a href="'.home_url() . '/' . $category_slug . '/'. $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(strlen($term_list) > 0){ echo '<div class="nav-back">&lsaquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. __('Back to ', 'theretailer').$term_list.'</div>'; };
            ?>

            <?php if (function_exists('be_previous_post_link')) { ?>
            <div class="nav-next-single"><?php be_next_post_link( '%link', '', true,'', 'product_cat' ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-previous-single"><?php be_previous_post_link( '%link', '', true,'', 'product_cat' ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-prev-next-txt"><?php _e('Prev / Next', 'theretailer'); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code hack could do what you want...

```
<?php
    $term_list = '';
    $j=0;
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if($term->parent==0){
            $j++;
            if( $j <= 1 ){
                $url=home_url() . '/' . $category_slug . '/'. $term->slug;
                if($url=='http://zanifesto.com/product-category/infographics'){
                    $url='http://zanifesto.com/gallery';
                }
                $term_list .= '<a href="'. $url . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    if(strlen($term_list) > 0){ echo '<div class="nav-back">&lsaquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. __('Back to ', 'theretailer').$term_list.'</div>'; };
?>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it says if 'home_url() . '/' . $category_slug . '/'. $term->slug;' happens to equal http://zanifesto.com/product-category/infographics, then it should use the gallery url?

Comment: Can I hard code the term name in a similar way? I tried adding  `if($term->name=='Infographics'){$term->name='Gallery';`  but it didn't like that.

Comment: if you set $term->name='Gallery' only the link text will change to gallery, you have to set the url in the href attribute of the anchor tag to "http://zanifesto.com/gallery", here i've added the variable $url within the string that forms the link